# Dealing with Client SSL certificate error in windows phone 8 silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, ssl, windows-phone-8.1

I am creating a Windows phone 8 (Silverlight) application using c#.

It uses web service for fetching data. And there is a .crt certificate file need to be included for a successful web response. So I need to include those certificate with the application for getting the successful response.

I searched for the solution to this issue to many, and on web . But unfortunately I am seeing it is not possible from the following Stack Overflow link.

[Windows 8 Phone Client Certificate HTTPS authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15374124/windows-8-phone-client-certificate-https-authentication)

"You can add a certificate authority to the trusted authorities list, but adding Client SSL certificates is unsupported." from the ms [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/ff402533#BKMK_SecureSocketsLayerSSLcertificates)

I tried by adding the '.crt' file to the solution and tried to navigate by the web browser . It is asking to search for an application to install this file. And when i do ,I could not find any application there and I could not install this.

```
MyWebBrowser.Navigate(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/apps_mine_in.crt", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

[image]

I found that Windows Phone 8.1 application, fortunately it is possible to add certificatethe way it from the link [Including Self-Signed Certificates with your Windows Runtime based Windows Phone 8.1 apps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2014/06/05/including-self-signed-certificates-with-your-windows-runtime-based-windows-phone-8-1-apps.aspx). But it will not solve my problem.

Comment: I also tried to get client certificate authentication to work under SL/WinRT and haven't found a solution yet. Good luck, but I think it is not possible at this time. (Well, you could use a socket and encrypt the content yourself, but that is usually beyond project scope...

Answer (score 0):

Please, try to add certificate in .pem format. As I remember, only .pem format is supported. I  aslo use custom certificate, but for email ssl.

Comment: In what way it works in Windows Phone 8 when we add .pem format ?

Comment: @AidenStrydom Hi, can you please share the code logic to work with all certificate types in windows phone 8 ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I changed the extension to `.cer` instead of `.cre` and it installed without fail.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp7-sync/i-cant-download-crt-files-my-windows-7-phone/90ae0d1b-972c-40a6-9aca-aa8e1d61f69e